# Delphi firemonkey interprocess communication somehow possible?

Tags: delphi, ipc, firemonkey

I am desperate looking for some sort of interprocess communication, which must work with firemonkey.

I am converting some projects from Win32/64 to firemonkey, and I used IPC to communicate between smaller applications and a main application to exchange data.

On the Win only version, I used cromis ipc, but its not ported to firemonkey / osx, and I just cant find anything similar.

The process is this:

"Client" application send a command (string) to "main application". Main application interpret this string and returns data based on the command, also string.

Does anybody has an idea how I could realize this?

Comment: FireMonkey is cross-platform but IPC is largely platform-specific. Unless you use a cross-platform IPC library, the only real cross-platform IPC solution with a (more or less) uniform API is  TCP/UDP via BSD sockets. Other platform-specific options include pipes, signals, mailslots/mailboxes, message queues, shared memory, etc.

Comment: Maybe app tethering?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds from your q that you have not come across Delphi's DataSnap technology, which is one way of doing what you say you want.

Take a look at the example Server + Client that you'll find under your Delphi

Samples\Object Pascal\DataSnap\<s>Basic</s>FireDAC

folder.

What you need to do to try it out is to compile and run the server and compile and run the client with the server still running.  DataSnap isn't just about databases and datasets:  If you take a look at e.g. the Server + Client in the FireDAC folder, you'll find that
the ServerMethodsUnit of the server contains

```
TServerMethods = class(TDSServerModule)
  [...]
public
  { Public declarations }
  function EchoString(Value: string): string;
  function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
  function StreamGet: TStream;
  procedure StreamPost(AStream: TStream);
end;
```

and you can call these methods from the FMX client - see the Button1Click handler in the
ClientUnit of the client, which contains this code

```
procedure TClientForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AString: string;
begin
  AString := InputBox('Reverse String', 'Enter a String', '');
  if AString <> '' then
  begin
    FDStoredProcReverse.Params[0].Value := AString;
    FDStoredProcReverse.ExecProc;
    ShowMessage(FDStoredProcReverse.Params[1].AsWideString);
  end;
end;
```

So it can do exactly what you said you needed in a comment, i.e. send a string from the client to the server and have the server pass a string back.
DataSnap works with FireMonkey and VCL and can use TCP or Http as its transport.

If you google

datasnap white paper

the first hit should be a white paper about the version of the "modern" DataSnap that was introduced in Delphi 2009 & 2010.  Unfortunately, the link is to Embarcadero's EDN server but that seems to be down at the moment from here (UK) as it often is at weekends.

Comment: I get right away an error TDSServer not found or something like that. It also looks like it would need a database of some sort. Thats all to intensive for what I want to do. I simply want to send a string to a main app, and that sent me a string back. There is sure some easy way to do that, at least I hope so.

Comment: Try the FireDAC example I've updated my answer to mention (of course, you need to have the server running while you try out the the client - in the new-style DataSnap, requesting a connection from the client doesn't automatically start the server as it used to the D7-style DCOM or ScktSrvr,Exe way of doing things ).

Comment: I cant open the FireDac example, I get "Class TFDPhysDSDriverLink not found." when opening the project. Is there any multi platform IPC component available, commercial or free?